# How to display a pop up once every 30 days with local storage

Tags: javascript, html, popup, local-storage

I have a newsletter pop up on my site that is currently showing up every time users click on different pages. I need this pop up to only show up for each user once every 30 days and was hoping I could do this with local storage. I haven't got much experience with local storage and was hoping someone may be able to explain to me how this would be done. Below is the limited amount of code i have started off with:

```js
  var newsletterPopup = localStorage.getItem('newsletter');

  if (newsletterPopup) {

  }

  localStorage.setItem('newsletter','true');
```

Comment: Store the current timestamp when the popup gets shown, and then check the difference between that stored timestamp, and the current one when you need to check whether it should get shown again already, or not.

Comment: (FYI, Safari has recently started to limit localStorage to a maximum storage duration of seven days, to increase privacy and prevent extended tracking attempts. So unless the user visits your site again within that interval, so that you can set this entry again, this might not work for your intended use case to begin with.)

Comment: ahh i see, so would i have to use a different method other than localStorage to achieve the 30 day time period?

Comment: They apply similar restrictions to cookies as well though, https://clearcode.cc/blog/intelligent-tracking-prevention-faq/#ITP-restrictions

Comment: I think I may be able to get away with showing the pop up once per visit instead of once every 30 days. would this be possible with local storage. Thanks for the link too i'l definitely give it a read